# Select every first and last IP Address of subnet ranges

Tags: python, python-3.x, subnet

I have a subnet `172.16.0.0/22` where I have four ranges `172.16.0.0 → 172.16.0.255` , `172.16.1.0 → 172.16.1.255`, `172.16.2.0 → 172.16.2.255`, and `172.16.3.0 → 172.16.3.255`. I am using `netaddr` to find these ranges.

```py
import netaddr

network = netaddr.IPNetwork(addr="172.16.0.0/22")

print(list(network))
```

```py
# output
[
IPAddress("172.16.0.0"), 
IPAddress("172.16.0.1"),
...,
IPAddress("172.16.0.254"),
IPAddress("172.16.0.255"),
...,
IPAddress("172.16.1.0"),
IPAddress("172.16.1.1"),
...,
IPAddress("172.16.1.254"),
IPAddress("172.16.1.255"),
...,
IPAddress("172.16.2.0"),
IPAddress("172.16.2.1"),
...,
IPAddress("172.16.2.254"),
IPAddress("172.16.2.255"),
...,
IPAddress("172.16.3.0"),
IPAddress("172.16.3.1"),
...,
IPAddress("172.16.3.254"),
IPAddress("172.16.3.255"),
]
```

How can I pick **every** `.1` and `.254` of every range? i.e., How can I get an output that looks like this

```py
[
    (172.16.0.1, 172.16.0.254), 
    (172.16.1.1, 172.16.1.254),
    (172.16.2.1, 172.16.2.254),
    (172.16.3.1, 172.16.3.254)
]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
result = [(str(network[256 * r + 1]), str(network[256 * r + 254]))
          for r in range(len(network) // 256)]
```

Basically for every range (there are `len(network) // 256` ranges) you take the element n. 1 (`network[256 * r + 1]`) and n. 254 (`network[256 * r + 254]`). Those elements are instances of class `<class 'netaddr.ip.IPAddress'>`: in order to convert them to strings you can just use the `str` built-in function.

Comment: Works like a charm! But can you please explain? Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tried this with a netaddr object but the code should also run as is because I covert the addresses to strings. It's not exactly what you wanted though. The addresses, per range are saved in lists.

```py
network = [
"172.16.0.0","172.16.0.1","172.16.0.254","172.16.0.255","172.16.1.0",
"172.16.1.1","172.16.1.254","172.16.1.255","172.16.2.0","172.16.2.1",
"172.16.2.254","172.16.2.255","172.16.3.0",
"172.16.3.1","172.16.3.254","172.16.3.255",
]

def get_adress(network):
    output,tmp = [],[]
    for ad in network:
        ad_str = str(ad)

        if ad_str.endswith('.1') or ad_str.endswith('.254'):
            tmp.append(ad_str)
            if len(tmp)==2:
                output.append(tmp)
                tmp= []
    return(output)

output= get_adress(network)
print(output)

>>[['172.16.0.1', '172.16.0.254'],
 ['172.16.1.1', '172.16.1.254'],
 ['172.16.2.1', '172.16.2.254'],
 ['172.16.3.1', '172.16.3.254']]
```

## Edit

This now has the addresses as tuples in a list.

```py
def get_adress(network):
    one,two = [],[]

    for ad in network:
        ad_str = str(ad)
        if ad_str.endswith('.1'): 
            one.append(ad_str)
        elif ad_str.endswith('.254'):
            two.append(ad_str)

    return(list(zip(one, two)))

output= get_adress(network)
output

>>[('172.16.0.1', '172.16.0.254'),
 ('172.16.1.1', '172.16.1.254'),
 ('172.16.2.1', '172.16.2.254'),
 ('172.16.3.1', '172.16.3.254')]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. I actually thought of the same exact way you did. Mine was `first_ips = [str(ip) for ip in network if str(ip).endswith(".1")] last_ips = [str(ip) for ip in network if str(ip).endswith(".254")] ips = list(zip(start_ips, last_ips))`. But the answer I accepted makes more sense and is more elegant. Again, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Checking the last octate in each IP Address to see if they are either of the desired numbers. I like this solution more as it uses only the `netaddr` object structure.

```
[n for n in network if n.words[-1] in [1, 254]]
```

Comment: Remember to convert the results to strings. Also, the user does not want to have a plain list, but a list of tuples